# Помогите построить SQL-запрос

Tags: mysql, mysqli

```
UPDATE tecdoc_cross, insert_parts_test 
SET tecdoc_cross.cross_num = IF(tecdoc_cross.cross_num = 0 , 
                                MAX(tecdoc_cross.cross_num) + 1 , 
                                tecdoc_cross.cross_num)
WHERE tecdoc_cross.art = insert_parts_test.art 
   OR tecdoc_cross.art = insert_parts_test.art_cross
```

Вообщем не работает только из-за `MAX(tecdoc_cross.cross_num) + 1`
Помогите пожалуйста найти решение.
`tecdoc_cross` имеет около 5 млн. строк
`insert_parts_test` имеет около 38 млн строк.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте что-нибудь типа

```
UPDATE tecdoc_cross tc, 
       insert_parts_test ipt, 
       ( SELECT @tmp := MAX(cross_num) 
         FROM tecdoc_cross) var
SET tc.cross_num = (@tmp := @tmp + 1)
WHERE tc.cross_num = 0
  AND tc.art IN (ipt.art, ipt.art_cross)
```